# stop Ipod from asking for old Apple ID password

Tags: ipod-touch, apple-id, password, accounts

Recently, I've changed my Apple ID because my old E-mail has been hacked. Now that I set the new one as my apple ID, the old Apple account still appears when I open almost all my apps on my Ipod Touch (4th Gen.), asking for the password to my old Apple ID. When I put in the old password to my old Apple ID, it'll keep asking for it no matter how many times I type it in. How do I fix this while keeping my account secure? Any suggestions would help!